# Unity set Gameobject based on parameter 'Type'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a strategy game. When I click the "BuildHouse" button in my action bar I want my manager to register the building that should be built.

All my buildings are components so I try to pass in the building type as a parameter.

My button executes

```
public void BuildFarm()
{
    buildManager.SetBuilding(typeof(Farm)); // Farm is a child of Building
}
```

Now the `BuildManager` knows the type of the building. I tried to iterate through all the building prefabs and pick the one that matches the type.

```
public class BuildManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] buildings;

    public void SetBuilding(Type buildingType)
    {
        GameObject targetBuilding = buildings.Where(currentBuilding => buildingType == currentBuilding.GetComponent<Building>().GetType()).First();
    }
}
```

I don't know if there is a better way to make the `BuildManager` get to know what to build. If this idea is bad at all please provide a better way of implementation.

Comment: Why not use `enum` as building type instead of component?

Comment: because I would have to compare it with the component of the building anyway

Comment: `buildings` array is the component with different types? Is this a prefab? Can you post your building type components?

Comment: `buildings` is an array of prefabs. There prefabs contain a component of type `Building`. Currently I have two components deriving from `Building`, these are `House` and `Farm`

Comment: Ok . Like I said in my first comment, enum makes more sense than what you have now. Also, you can use `interface` to accomplish the-same thing too. Just make `IHouse` and `IFarm` interfaces then use `GetComponent` to decide which one the prefab is

Comment: Could you explain how this would improve the code? Because then I would have to use a switch and with that code I don't have to. I mean it's dynamic.

Comment: You asked for a better way to do this then I explained to you two other better ways to do it. You will have to use the `if` or `switch` statement for them too. I noticed you'been complaining about them. There is nothing wrong with using them. Note that your `buildings.Where` code is doing that under the hood too but slower than doing it yourself manually.

Comment: What does the `BuildManager` do after you call `SetBuilding`? Does it instantiate a new GameObject for that building?

Comment: @pbalaga yes I think so. I would create a GO out of the selected prefab.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion filtering by component type is absolutely fine. If you have `Farm` and `House` components and they are both buildings, it's natural to express it with an inheritance hierarchy.

As concerns using `enum`: enums are best at representing simple state or well-specified values that are unlikely to change, e.g. [days of week](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx). There will be no 8th day of week, right? On the other hand, you may want to freely extend the list of available buildings, and each building may implement different game logic. A more natural way to express that is to create a class hierarchy. And when the classes are in place, adding an `enum` for the same thing is superfluous.

That said, I'd suggest some improvements in your code.

```
    public void SetBuilding<TBuilding>() where TBuilding : IBuilding
    {
        GameObject targetBuilding = buildings
           .Where(currentBuilding => 
              typeof(TBuilding) == currentBuilding.GetComponent<Building>().GetType())
           .SingleOrDefault();

        if(targetBuilding == null)
        {
           // throw or log an error here
        }
        else
        {
           // instantiate
        }
    }
```

1. If `buildingType` is always known at compile-time you can use generics. It makes calls to this method slightly more readable:
   `buildManager.SetBuilding<Farm>();`
2. Notice the `where TBuilding : IBuilding` constraint. Make your `Farm` and `House` classes implement a common interface `IBuilding` (it could be a common base class too): `class Farm : Component, IBuilding`. By this compiler ensures you can't call something like `buildManager.SetBuilding<int>();`
3. `SingleOrDefault` ensures there's exactly one such GO. In case there's none or more than 1, it returns null. If that's the case, throw or log an error. I know you are making sure the `buildings` array is correct but you should enforce it with code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest defining an `enum`:

```
enum BuildingType
{
    Farm,
    House,
    ...
}
```

Then you can define a `Type` property for `Building`:

```
public class Building
{
    ...
    BuildingType Type { get; set; }
    ... 
}
```

Then you can call `SetBuilding` like this (maybe use a `switch`):

```
public void SetBuilding(BuildingType buildingType)
{
    // act according to buildingType
}
```

Comment: How would it improve my code shown above? Because with your example I would have to create a switch. Using my code, there would be no switch needed ..

Comment: I'm not sure what _exactly_ are you trying to do in `SetBuilding`, but maybe you can do this: 
`GameObject targetBuilding = buildings.Where(currentBuilding => currentBuilding.Type == buildingType).First();`

Comment: Also, consider using `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`, if you encounter a null-case.

Comment: Well `targetBuilding` must not be null because this would be an ingame bug. When clicking the build button there would be nothing to build.

Comment: I mean the `Where` clause can return `null` if there is no building object in `buildings` with such `Type`, just saying.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But there must be no error, I have to make sure that everything is assigned correctly.